# Format field in header file invalid for GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-7.2

I have a raster map in GRASS database. When i try to load using

```
d.rast map=Raster-name
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to run command.
>
> Details: GRASS_INFO_ERROR(9937,1):Raster map (Raster-name) :format
>   field in header file invalid GRASS_INFO(9937,1)

---

But my header file for that layer seems to be okay.

> proj:       99
>
> zone:       0
>
> north:      605142.56603693
>
> south:      183380.37076456
>
> east:       1292651.17488958
>
> west:       922758.12807321
>
> cols:       3699
>
> rows:       4218
>
> e-w resol:  99.99812025
>
> n-s resol:  99.99103729
>
> format:     -1
>
> compressed: 2

---

I have tried to copy to a different name both in same and different dataset. But the error still occurs.